# how do get a list of IDs from a model based on an association to another model

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have Company that has many customers. Customer has_many Messages. Messages have a text attribute.

I'm trying to get a list of customer_ids from customers who don't have a specific word in the text attribute of their messages. Here's what I have so far:

```
company.customers.includes(:messages).references(:messages).where('messages.text NOT LIKE ?', "% summer %")
```

when I do that and get a count of the customers in that group, it is the right number (about 7500) but when I go to pluck the ids like so:

```
company.customers.includes(:messages).references(:messages).where('messages.text NOT LIKE ?', "% summer %").pluck(:id).count
```

it returns like 80000 results, which isn't correct

what am i doing wrong?

EDIT: error from trying answer:

```
PG::AmbiguousColumn: ERROR:  column reference "id" is ambiguous
LINE 1: SELECT id FROM "customers" LEFT OUTER JOIN "messages" ON "me...
               ^
: SELECT id FROM "customers" LEFT OUTER JOIN "messages" ON "messages"."customer_id" = "customers"."id" WHERE "customers"."company_id" = $1 AND (messages.text NOT LIKE '% summer %')
PG::AmbiguousColumn: ERROR:  column reference "id" is ambiguous
LINE 1: SELECT id FROM "customers" LEFT OUTER JOIN "messages" ON "me...
               ^
: SELECT id FROM "customers" LEFT OUTER JOIN "messages" ON "messages"."customer_id" = "customers"."id" WHERE "customers"."company_id" = $1 AND (messages.text NOT LIKE '% summer %')
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::AmbiguousColumn: ERROR:  column reference "id" is ambiguous
LINE 1: SELECT id FROM "customers" LEFT OUTER JOIN "messages" ON "me...
```

Comment: What if you remove the `.references(:messages)` from the Query? (`.joins` triggers a `INNER JOIN` which creates duplicates, `.includes` triggers a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` which does not create duplicates)

Comment: but I'm not using a .joins...where would i put that?

Comment: Just try `company.customers.includes(:messages).where('messages.text NOT LIKE ?', "% summer %").count` to see if it works. If it does, I'll post an answer explaning the issue here

Answer (score 1):

Try with:

```
company.customers.includes(:messages).references(:messages).where('messages.text NOT LIKE ?', "% summer %").distinct.pluck(:id).count
```

Answer (score 0):

Just chain `ids` to the end of your query:

```
company.customers.includes(:messages).references(:messages).where('messages.text NOT LIKE ?', "% summer %").ids
```

You should also be able to remove the references:

```
company.customers.includes(:messages).where('messages.text NOT LIKE ?', "% summer %").ids
```

Comment: that didn't work. got a bunch of errors (shown in edit)

Comment: should also mention it should be "company.customers" rather than "company.customer"...that's my mistake..fixed in edit

Comment: @MatthewBerman `.pluck(:id)` is ambiguous because Rails does not know which `id` column you want.

Comment: What version of Rails are you using. 4.1.2 properly queries contacts.id not just id under Postgres and MySQL for me.

Answer (score 0):

There are same "id" fields in the query (customers, messages) so you need to add an id field to order it. You can add reorder(:id) so it'll order by customer id for you.

Try this:

```
company.customers.includes(:messages).references(:messages).where('messages.text NOT LIKE ?', "% summer %").reorder(:id).pluck(:id)
```